# VS Code Live Server will not go live on windows

Tags: html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, liveserver

Im using VS code and when I try to see how my code looks online(go live) the page is either blank or if I select run to cursor it shows my code just how I wrote it on VS code and not how the browser shows it. It use to show it but not  anymore. The  only time  it shows my work  is  when I go live with  the udemy zip files I download for  class projects. It works for those files but once I create a new boiler plate/ file  nothing. Can someone help please. I have A dell G515 windows. ill be attaching screen shots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkJcE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQdV.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzEFO.png)

I tried restarting both apps  and logging in with my profiles, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your "boilerplate" file "boilerplate.html". And if you want to have something appear when launching the live server, you either have to put that something in a HTML file in the root of your VS Code workspace folder, or in whatever folder you have specified in your `liveServer.settings.root` setting.